# CALLBACK with oath2 foursquare

Tags: android, api, callback, foursquare

I created an activity where it's going to open the browser to ask you the permission of the application.
Here nothing strange but when the API redirect me to the callback give me back this error:

```
fis://test.com?error=redirect_uri_mismatch
```

Why?!

This is the code how I am going to open the browser:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authenticate"
            + "?client_id=" + Utils.FOURSQUARE_CLIENT_ID
            + "&response_type=code" + "&redirect_uri=fis://test.com"));
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
                            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY
                            | Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
    startActivity(intent);
```

It's very strange because the redirect is working, but the error says `redirect_url_mismatch`

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure the redirect url you've specified in the client settings at foursquare (https://foursquare.com/oauth) is exactly the same as the one you're using,  including the protocol.